# QTemporaryFile permission denied on Mac OS X Sierra Qt 5.7

Tags: macos, qt, macos-sierra

I have an issue with QTemporaryFile on Mac OS X sierra

When launching my app bundle from Finder I get error while trying to open QTemporaryFile (Permission Denied). When launching same app but from terminal or QtCreator the or even from finder but directly from app bundle then everything is fine - QTemporaryFiles is created and everything works. Did anyone came through this problem? Maybe it's lack of some entries in Info.plist file? Or maybe it's a bug in Qt?

// EDIT

After more research it seems that it affects only QTemporaryFile with file name template